# ImportJson Funtion retrieve columns in different positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I'm using a function to get and process a JSON object and display the information on a google spreadsheet. Working fine.

I'm calling the function in 5 sheets using different filters on the query.

The issue I'm having is that on each page the order of the attributes changes.
In some spreadsheet the "Name" is in column A, and in another is in column D, the same as the other ones.

The code is using a multidimensional array, I wonder if I could fix the position of the attributes on the array, so Name will always be displayed in the same column in every page.

The script I'm currency using:
 https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON

```
[{
        "_id" : {
            "$oid" : "2342hgiug2343242gi"
        },
        "ID" : "HHT-6",
        "Link" : "SomeLink",
        "Name" : "Some Description",
        "Type" : "Request",
        "Team" : null,
        "Release" : null,
        "Stage" : "Open",
        "Level" : null,
        "Labels" : "[3244234,234234;]",
        "Versions" : null,
        "Components" : null,
        "DevelopmentSize" : null,
        "Class of Service" : "Standard",
        "Resolution" : null,
        "Location" : null,
        "Main Category" : null,
        "First Category" : null,
        "Second Category" : null,
        "Key" : "HHT",
        "Created" : "2016-02-12"
    }
]
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include a sample of the JSON data, I'm guessing it is using objects rather than arrays to to represent the data, but need to see it to confirm.

Comment: In order to understand about your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet that it is used? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: You could augment the function to take an optional parameter, the range containing the desired headers to output (and thus also the desired order).

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest version

https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs

So, to the paths be returned in the requested order, You have to pass the '**allHeaders**' option parameter.

```
=ImportJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"; "/title,/invalidColumn,/completed"; "allHeaders")
```

Observe **`/invalidColumn`** is also returned.